# How to make all subclasses necessarily conform to protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

I have a base class `SLBaseViewController` which is a subclass of UIViewController and want  all its subclasses to conform to protocol:

```
@protocol SLLocalizable <NSObject>

- (void)localize;

@end
```

The problem is that I don't need `SLBaseViewController` to conform to protocol itself, but I need compiler to warn me if a subclass doesn't conform.

What I have tried:

1. Define base class like this:

   ```
   @interface SLBaseViewController : UIViewController <SLLocalizable>
   ```

   In this case compiler tells me that `SLBaseViewController` does not implement `localize` method.
2. Make `localize` optional.

   Compiler keeps silence. But that's not what I need.
3. Make each of subclasses conform to protocol itself. That seems to be a right way, but I have more than 50 subclasses and it's a long way.

Is there a simple way to reach my goal?

Comment: Search for the subclasses to edit them. Make the superclass throw an exception if it's called so you know when you missed something.

Comment: @Wain Good idea, thank you. Would you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't specify that the subclasses implement any protocol other than to specify it in the subclass itself.

Search for the subclasses to edit them (rather than trying to remember each). A reflex search would be able to find subclasses which don't give the protocol name.

As a safety check, make the superclass throw an exception if it's called so you know when you missed something. Obviously this only works during testing.

If this makes you paranoid, you could try writing a unit test which [gets all the subclasses](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/getting-subclasses-of-objective-c-class.html) and calls `localize` on them.

Answer (score 1):

In what case would you need all subclasses to implement something, but don't need the common superclass to implement it?

If it is that `SLBaseViewController` is an abstract class that is not meant to be instantiated directly, you can simply have it implement `-localize`, and in the body throw an exception. Or, you can simply ignore the warning (it is just a warning after all).